# Problem with dynamic result stored procedure call using linq

Tags: linq

In one of my application i want to use dynamic column diaply using stored procedure.

How can i achieve that ???

```
USE [ASIF]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_GET_TABLE]    Script Date: 11/03/2010 15:45:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GET_TABLE]
 @TABLENAME VARCHAR(100),
 @SELECT VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @pQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @pQUERY = 'SELECT '+ @SELECT +' FROM '+ @TABLENAME

 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @pQUERY
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky! In case of Linq to SQL. Try this:

```
        string tableName = "TABLENAME";

        switch(tableName)
        {
            case "Table1":
                Table1Type abc = yourEntityContext.ExecuteQuery(Table1Type, "exec USP_GET_TABLE", new object[] { "TABLENAME", "SELECT param" });
                break;

        }
```